# Unable to change the top color of a TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

On WinForm, I use a `TabControl` but I can't change the top color (see red circle)

For several hours, I try to put the top of the `TabControl` of the same color as my `Form`, that is to say in gray but impossible.

Do you know a solution ?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: That part of TabControl is transparent, showing the parent control's content.  Plenty of black around it so not that mysterious.  Use View > Other Windows > Document Outline if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, precisely it is not transparent.. if you put a yellow panel underneath for example then you will see black

Comment: That's a good way to never solve the problem.  Use Document Outline, it is good at showing parent-child relationships, avoiding the vague notion of "panel underneath".

Comment: View / Other Windows / Document Outline. `Ctrl+W, U`.

Comment: We did not find a fix to this issue, so we decided to draw our custom TabControl from scratch https://ibb.co/8mGGf4y .Unfortunately, I can not share the code.